GluonFX JavaFX Substrate run dynamically loaded classes
A JavaFX application that loads jar(s) at runtime and
the classes within the jar must run within the application.
These dynamically loaded classes implement an interface.
Using Gluon with graalVM, is there any possibility of running the code that was
loaded?
From what I understand about GraalVM it will only run static codes, or is there
Is there any way to run classes dynamically at runtime?
In the real world, I have an application that does exactly this running on the JVM.
--------- ENVIRONMENT
Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
java version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.3+7.1 (build 21.0.3+7-LTS-jvmci-23.1-b37)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.3+7.1 (build 21.0.3+7-LTS-jvmci-23.1-b37, mixed mode, sharing)
apache-maven-3.8.6

See: GraalVM: build a native shared library.  From the info in the link I provided, what you propose seems feasible.  However, I have never used GraalVM and do not know if that is truly so or not.

A possible approach is to build the shared library based on the jar file. Graal generates header files you can invoke, and "If you work with C or C++, use these header files directly. For other languages, such as Java, use the function declarations in the headers to set up your foreign call bindings."  See also Interoperability with Native code and implementing native methods.

Also, see Native Image Compatibility and Optimization Guide: there are various restrictions and limitations when using native images that you will need to be aware of and potentially workaround for your approach to work.
